# ¿Por qué Auth::user()->id me devuelve siempre la misma ID para diferentes usuarios en Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

También ¿cómo podría obtener la ID de cada usuario en sesión?

Esto lo necesito para mostrar datos diferentes para cada usuario conectado, y al devolverme siempre la misma ID, muestro lo mismo.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Luego editar y agrega un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te servirá porque necesitaría algo más específico, pero generalmente en Laravel yo devuelvo el auth como si fuera una función. auth()->user()->id, por ejemplo.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).